# Is it good to handle socket connection status via a timer?

Tags: c#, vb.net, sockets, timer

In Server/Client Applications, is it a memory consumption to use a timer that checks for each client if it is connected or not?

For example a `Socket` Server accepts a `Socket` Client and add it to a List, then a timer that checks each Client in the List via a loop, if it is not connected then removed from the `List<>` and fire an event... however though this way sounds hard especially that the timer's interval is 1 second... plus if there let's say 1000 client Connected, can the timer checks them all in 1 second? or should i make it bigger?

I care about the memory used by my app, and the timer capability of checking many clients in 1 sec. is that a true way? thanks in advanced.

Comment: Without any code it's hard to give specific advice (hence comment and not answer), but no - I would say it's not good.  Instead, use the events that are raised when things disconnect, and be ready to handle exceptions from disconnected clients.

Comment: I didn't use code because the questions will be long and unanswerable plus my question is pretty specific, thanks for answer, i thought that too but using events and handling exceptions are not that accurate than this way, is that right?

Comment: If anything, they're _more_ accurate, especially handling exceptions.  Lets say you have a connected client, your timer checks and sees they're connected.  They then disconnect.  You still think they're connected and try to send a message before the next loop of the timer.  Exception - need to handle it anyway.

Comment: that's correct but the timer checks every 1 second and it's fine if there is a 1 sec delay before the event raised.. you said the "next loop of the timer" is it possible that this loop takes more than 1 second?

Comment: It's possible, but also 1 second is a _very long time_ in computer terms.  It's very feasible to have someone disconnect between you checking they're connected and sending a message, no matter _how long_ the timer timeout is.  You absolutely have to handle the exception at the very least, but as above I'd look into using events raised when clients disconnect as the method for tracking such things.

Comment: so by using events i won't need the timer right? i mean handling most of the necessary exceptions will be enough?

Comment: With approx. 1000 clients connected you should think about inversion of control: instead of the server pings all clients, the clients should rather send a heartbeat to the server every x seconds. Google heartbeat pattern or ask for more info.

Comment: @Alex B. that's a brilliant idea... why wouldn't i think of using that from the beginning.. appreciate your idea

Answer (score 1):

No it's not a good idea because it already implements such a mechanism, the [Timeout](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.receivetimeout(v=vs.110).aspx) in both send operations and receive operations, meaning that if you set a receive timeout for 10 sec, call the [Receive](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8s4y8aff(v=vs.110).aspx) and nothing comes, it will already throw a exception, notifying you as you want to do with the timer...

Answer (score 0):

The last time i created a server/client app like the one you are describing, i created a new thread with priority set a BelowNormal.

The only thing with Timers is that they (potentially) execute inside the UI thread meaning your form will become unresponsive or laggy.

Then i basically looped the thread continuously inside a Do/While loop until the application closed. Throw in a quick Threading.Thread.Sleep(100) and performance will be perfect.

Inside the loop, i'd check for incoming connection requests and like you say, add them to a list etc. You can then also handle communications with each connected client too as it'll have minimal impact.

```
Private Sub StartSocketsServer()
    Try
        Dim oThread As New Threading.Thread(AddressOf StartSocketsServer_Threaded)
        With oThread
            .Name = "Socket Server"
            .Priority = Threading.ThreadPriority.BelowNormal
            .IsBackground = True
            .Start()
        End With
    Catch ex As Exception
        'Handle exception
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub StartSocketsServer_Threaded()
    Try
        Do
            'Perform all of your sockets here in a threaded environment.


            Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000) '1 sec

        Loop Until Me.IsDisposed

    Catch ex As Exception
        'Handle thread safe exceptions here
    End Try
End Sub
```